# I download excel using Box spout error , can not be download

Tags: spout

I use box spout to export excel file. Version box spout : 3.3. I use `$writer->openToBrowser($linkFile);` let it download automatically, but it doesn't download,
error like this

```
!*QQ¤fãXwfîñc\L7ÍÖÑxW²²òÚ¸EÉÞçÏùË0I§¥õJ¶dÓÉ o`FÉKV§î@UC#ûÊÇF&ÆR-åÄx8¼Ê».å©­Á&¾â*¹²){èÅ¶~ÉdÖ(NPE=mHìYÛ¹87yíôV¾Câlµ xsìB*~Û¼ÒFE£áW>¾ªíÕª¡!ÔX¤Æònä4®wÉ^dCUÅÆOÞ/y¿Ö+ø·ÝÿOö¢Fÿc¼ã¸Ö¤­<Ò+üðæ]ãJÈú-EjÁÓÃìû@ùy¤ÆdN¬pg¤¢hÿ| m9
ú,*½(D÷M¾PK¸Rþ;ãxl/workbook.xmlÏNÃ0Æï}Èw®ª¶»LH»òç²Æ]£%qoOÖÐøÇ±ù>w»àÕ3;=l75(#YO=¼¾<Þ=b1ÑO{øDÝPuïÏG¢³*ó{ER«53ÃJËËD9)×|Ò2Ë3¢¯º¾×Á¸+¡ÍÿaÐ4¹÷4¾²B2z#E=Ï.1*Ñ-ßð°*P¤?a¢,ÅÎµv°Å-¨Üºä}¾·W)½Çîèô-Ú£ç¿¤æi¦¿UþYáðPK¸RÐu:µð
xl/styles.xmlÅTMo0½çWX¾7ÒVQeHH½ô­Ô«ülo
```

It shows up in the browser. How to fix this please help me

Comment: Have you tried downgrading to the 3.2 version, just in case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a variable that points to that saved file. And use `js` to open the link. And it downloads itself.